Unable to get python code to match Whatsapp template with Twilio
My approved template:
enter image description here
My function:
def send_whatsapp_message(message_text, input_value): 
    load_dotenv() token = os.getenv("TWILIO_TOKEN") 
    sid = os.getenv("TWILIO_SID") 
    from_number = os.getenv("TWILIO_NUMBER")  
    to_numbers = ast.literal_eval(os.getenv( 'NOTIFY_NUMBERS'))  

for to_number in to_numbers:
    try:
        # Validate number format
        if not to_number.startswith("whatsapp:+"):
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid number format: {to_number}")

        # Replace placeholders in the message
        final_message = message_text.format(input_value)
        final_message = final_message.replace("\\n", "\n")

        message = client.messages.create(
            from_=from_number,
            to=to_number,
            body=final_message
        )
        print(f"Message sent successfully to {to_number}: {message.sid}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to send message to {to_number}: {e}")

Example of my inputs:
template_message = "ERROR Message from Decent Energy:\n{}"
send_whatsapp_message(template_message, "Test-message")
`
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? The code runs successfully, but then when I look at Twilio I get error 63016: https://help.twilio.com/articles/360038232293-Error-63016-Failed-to-send-freeform-message-because-you-are-outside-the-allowed-window-Please-use-a-Template-when-Sending-Programmable-Messages-to-WhatsApp
I've tried changing how I provide the input, the new line etc, but nothing seems to be working
